# How to make vim jump to first tag by default

Tags: vim, editor, ctags

I am working in Red Hat. I've found that the Vim in this OS won't jump to first tag by default when I execute `:ta foo`.

For example, there are several tags named "foo". And now I entered `:ta foo`, it will show up just like `:ts foo`. So every time I have to input `q 1` to jump to the first. It seems quite inconvenient. Can I change it?

Comment: for me `:ta foo` works as expexted: Vim jumps to the first tag instead of showing the list of available tags. Make sure you have not overrided `:ta` somewhere.

Comment: It works just fine under ubuntu. But not in redhat. Maybe it caused by   different versions of vim. `:ta` haven't been remap in vimrc.

Comment: @user674199: I don't believe that this behavior is due to different vim versions. See :help :ta. It clearly describes that :ta without further options jumps to the first tag. My guess is that the command :ta is remapped, e.g. by a plugin. What does :command say? Disable/remove all plug-ins and retry.

Comment: @habi Thanks habi. You are right. After i remapping `:ta` to `:ta` again, it works fine. But i haven't found anything about tag in `:command`.

Comment: Try `:verbose command ta` to find where you mapped `:ta`.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the following setting in my .vimrc prevented  from jumping to the first tag.

`set cscopetag`

Comment: This answer is useful. It's located in cscope_maps.vim:34. I comment it out and tag/ptag works fine.

Comment: Bless you! You basically saved me from 10+ hours of debugging. Who would have thought what I was looking for lied in `vim/bundle/neocomplcache/autoload/neocomplcache/sources/vim_complete/options.dict` :)